# Error adding NSEntity to a NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, swift2

I have 2 Entities in my `CoreData` structure , there is a One-to-many relationship between them. In the Main Entity I have a NSOrderdSet, every time I make a new save I want to add and save the 2nd entity in the NSOrderdSet, but I get an Error.
 Here is my code:

```
//main Entity 
class Project : NSManagedObject {
func requestAddNewWeek (value: WeekContent) {
let mutableCopyOfSet = projectContent?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderdSet
mutableCopyOfSet.addObject(value)
projectContent = mutableCopyOfSet.copy() as ? NSOderedSet
}
}

// ViewController where the save occurs
class SetupWeekViewController {
var project : Project?

@IBAction func saveButton (sender : AnyObject) {
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
 let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Content", inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
//Here is where the error happens
project!requestAddNewWeek(newWeek)

managedContext.save()
}
```

//Here is the error I get

```
2015-12-08 11:07:13.392 MySightwords[1998:189666] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/Len/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0215DFE7-14EA-459F-991C-5ABF8020712D/data/Containers/Data/Application/7A509174-D568-4CCE-8A3D-9710FF80A9BF/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Content = <16a6b5d3 e57d053c f85d1afa 2efe7c04 8da974e7 127f2c6b 847ea2f0 b63d732f>;
        Project = <97588fff 696dabc6 896ec617 564b473f f3bc9bdc e6c891b3 84519149 9319c454>;
        Sightwords = <6bf96219 adc3369d 4eec0597 b40472c3 d3af6a61 3d17bd5d 117885f4 509ecd2e>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "270A2DB1-BFDA-41A3-B044-DFBA717A1BDD";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Content = <16a6b5d3 e57d053c f85d1afa 2efe7c04 8da974e7 127f2c6b 847ea2f0 b63d732f>;
            Project = <97588fff 696dabc6 896ec617 564b473f f3bc9bdc e6c891b3 84519149 9319c454>;
            Sightwords = <6bf96219 adc3369d 4eec0597 b40472c3 d3af6a61 3d17bd5d 117885f4 509ecd2e>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "270A2DB1-BFDA-41A3-B044-DFBA717A1BDD";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}
2015-12-08 11:07:13.396 MySightwords[1998:189666] Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff7025e9200 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Content = <16a6b5d3 e57d053c f85d1afa 2efe7c04 8da974e7 127f2c6b 847ea2f0 b63d732f>;
        Project = <97588fff 696dabc6 896ec617 564b473f f3bc9bdc e6c891b3 84519149 9319c454>;
        Sightwords = <6bf96219 adc3369d 4eec0597 b40472c3 d3af6a61 3d17bd5d 117885f4 509ecd2e>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "270A2DB1-BFDA-41A3-B044-DFBA717A1BDD";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}}}, [NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Content = <16a6b5d3 e57d053c f85d1afa 2efe7c04 8da974e7 127f2c6b 847ea2f0 b63d732f>;
        Project = <97588fff 696dabc6 896ec617 564b473f f3bc9bdc e6c891b3 84519149 9319c454>;
        Sightwords = <6bf96219 adc3369d 4eec0597 b40472c3 d3af6a61 3d17bd5d 117885f4 509ecd2e>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "270A2DB1-BFDA-41A3-B044-DFBA717A1BDD";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}]
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can u show me the error

Comment: Ok I added  the error I get, its a bit long

Comment: Are you running the app in simulator?

Comment: Try Deleting your app and reinstall, this happens when you have changed your core data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to the change in your model.

Remove the app from the simulator and perform a clean on your project.

Note: This is for development only. For production, you need to implement some sort of migration. Google "Core Data Migration", with lightweight migration being the simplest.

Comment: After clearing my simulator , the app crashed , because it Unwrapped a nill. `project!requestAddNewWeek(newWeek)` Unwrapped as a nil.

Comment: I think a Data migration might work, because I changed the name of the Entity, so the store and model are not matching , so the project model will unwrap as a nil